# Laravel: Fatal Error: Memory Bytes Exhausted With Remote Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I have a Laravel (5.5) web app and I'm trying to get a remote database connected. I'm using Apache, PHP 7.0, and MySQL. Laravel uses PDO, and when the class is called with the remote DB info, I get a 500 Server Error:

`PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php on line 67`

A few notes:

- The app loads without issue when using the same database localy
- I can connect to the remote database using Sequel Pro
- I can also connect to the remote database from the command line of the Laravel server (as root)
- I've set the PHP memory_limit to -1

Here's my config file (same info in .env):

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'xxxxxx'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxxxx'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx'),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'sslmode' => env('DB_SSLMODE', 'prefer'),
    'options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem',
    ),   
],
```

If anybody has any thoughts or suggestions, that would be amazing.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Then I have to assume you did not edit the correct `php.ini` file. Or you did not restart Apache after editing it. As `134217728` looks pretty much like the default `128Meg` to me

Comment: Hmm, i'll double check, thanks for the heads up

Comment: I checked and the currently loaded php.ini memory_limit is set to -1. Restarted Apache just to make sure, still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by the grace of the folks over at larachat. The issue was with the Exception Handler. The `context()` function tries to get user data for error reporting. The handler will then attempt to query the database, and then report the error, and then attempt to get the user info, causing an infinite loop.

The temp fix was to modify the report() function in `/Foundation/Exception/Handler.php`:

```
$logger->error(
    $e->getMessage(),
    ['exception' => $e]
);
```